# Qt with WebAssembly setup issue

Tags: qt, webassembly

I am currently creating setup on MacOS for Qt with Web-Assembly.

I followed these two links - https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly and http://qtandeverything.blogspot.in

Steps Completed -

1. CMAKE installation
2. Python 2.7.10 setup

3.WASM ToolChain setup-

```
$ git clone https://github.com/juj/emsdk.git

$ cd emsdk

$ ./emsdk install --build=Release sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-64bit

$ ./emsdk activate --build=Release sdk-incoming-64bit binaryen-master-  64bit

$ source ./emsdk_env.sh --build=Release
```

==> And finally tested sample c program, it works fine.

```
 Ex- $ emcc hello.c -s WASM=1 -o hello.html
```

4.Downloaded Qt for emsdk

```
 Ex - git clone -b wip/webassembly https://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git
```

5.Also successfully run following two commands (/Path/To/Qt/5.11.0/Src/qtbase) -

```
$/configure -xplatform emscripten -confirm-license -opensource -developer-build -release -static -no-thread -nomake tests -nomake examples  -no-dbus -no-headersclean -no-feature-networkinterface  -system-libpng -no-ssl -no-warnings-are-errors

$make
```

**So my next requirement is to-  (Add emscripten compiler to Qt Creator)**

Found this link - **http://qtandeverything.blogspot.in** and step 4. suggests that to "Add emscripten compiler to Qt Creator".

So,My question is what is the way to create emscripten compiler in Qt Creator.?

Also please suggest me exact step to follow Qt with Webassembly

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

After your step 5 where you `make` inside of your qtbase folder, a qmake file will appear.  All you have to do to successfully compile a project is the following from inside of whichever Qt project folder you want to run in the browser:

```
/path/to/qmake/inside/qtbase && make
```

This will be limited to the project types that qtbase supports. 
You can refer link [Qt For WebAssembly](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but answering anyway.

Assuming you are now using 5.12 (beta) or repo

Yes there is a way to manually import the kit.

Tools->Options->Kits

```
* add Custom c++: name: emcc++ <path/to/emscripten>/emcc++
 - x86-linux-u generic-elf-64bit
 - mkspecs: wasm-emscripten

* add custom c: name: emcc <path/to/emscripten>/emcc
```

Qt Versions->

```
* add <navigate to your qt for wasm> qmake
```

Kits:

```
* add qt5-wasm
* compilers: emcc and emc++ 
* Qt Version: Qt for Webassembly
```